# Is the result of a CloudFront function run on the Viewer Request cached?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have implemented a simple URL redirect based on the incoming URI as a CloudFront function on the Viewer Request.

My expectation was that the CloudFront function would run once per URI, where the result would be cached for subsequent requests to that URI.

Looking at the metrics, I am noticing the function has a lot of invocations and am wondering if the result is cached or if the function is run every time there is a request?

The function itself is really simple:

```js
function handler(event) { 
  var request = event.request;
  var uri = event.request.uri;

  var redirects = {
    '/foo/': '/bar/'
  }

  var redirect = redirects[uri];
  if (redirect !== undefined) {
    var response = {
      statusCode: 302,
      statusDescription: "Found",
      headers: { location: { value: redirect } },
    };

    return response;
  }

  return request;
}
```

Should I move this to the Viewer Response if I want the response to be cached?